# Cannot set innerHTML or $(this).val successfully in AJAX function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using AJAX I have retrieved Json information but, during the function, I cannot display the text in the relevant Div.

The code works right to the bottom, as I can see using the console, but even if I put placeholder text in the div "place", the placeholder text stays the same right to the end of the function.

```
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                if(i===0){
                    var placeHTML='<h2>'+item.name+'</h2>' +
                    '<p>where you can get <br>' +
                    'a pint of <em>'+item.pint+'</em> for only<br>' +
                    '<span>£'+item.cost+'!</span></p>';

                    window.localStorage.setItem("placeName", item.name);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("placeLoc1", item.location);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("placeLoc2", item.location2);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("placeEmail", item.email);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("placeNumber", item.number);

                    console.log("Data saved");

                    document.getElementById("place").innerHtml = placeHTML;

                    console.log("Data placed:");
                    console.log(placeHTML);

                    $("#loadText").fadeOut();
                    $('#place').fadeIn();

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I have also tried replacing `document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = foo` to `$("#place").val(foo)` with no luck.

The div has the values `id="place"` and `class="place"`.

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Where does the ajax come in?

Comment: And why are you iterating over one instance only? and it's `.innerHTML = placeHTML` or `$('#place').html(placeHTML)` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("place").innerHtml = placeHTML;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = placeHTML;
```

to do it with jQuery

```
$("#place").html(placeHTML)
```

`val` will set the value of something like an input field, to change the inner HTML with jQuery you want to use the `html()` function

Comment: Thanks so much. Been up all night and am missing the silly little errors like that!

Comment: no problem.  Spotted it right away because I've done it myself before.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#place").html(foo)
```

Or

```
$("#place").text(foo)
```

Also, it is not `innerHtml`, it should be `innerHTML` here:

Change it to:

```
document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = placeHTML;
```

Comment: In this case `.text()` won't work because there's markup in the string.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan But what you have written in the end was contradicting. You said, *I have also tried replacing* `document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = foo`.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong,

```
document.getElementById("place").innerHtml = placeHTML;
```

Change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML` (HTML should be caps),

```
document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = placeHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try to use

```
$("#place").html(placeHTML);
```